# Displaying result in formatted way in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

One method to display result in formatted way is pretty() method.But,I have
 following error with method pretty()

db.mycol.find().pretty()

> {

... "title":"MongoDB is no sql database",

... "by":"tutorials point",

... "url":"http://www.tutorilaspoint.com",

... "tags":["mongodb","dtabase","NoSQL"],

... "likes":"100"

... }

2016-09-19T16:31:34.779+0545 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: provide your code

Comment: Its the same code from tutorialspoint >db.mycol.find().pretty()
{
   "_id": ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   "title": "MongoDB Overview", 
   "description": "MongoDB is no sql database",
   "by": "tutorials point",
   "url": "http://www.tutorialspoint.com",
   "tags": ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"],
   "likes": "100"
}
>

Comment: should be `pretty()` instead of `preety()`

Comment: db.mycol.find().pretty()
> {
... "title":"MongoDB is no sql database",
... "by":"tutorials point",
... "url":"http://www.tutorilaspoint.com",
... "tags":["mongodb","dtabase","NoSQL"],
... "likes":"100"
... }
2016-09-19T16:31:34.779+0545 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `db.mycol.find().pretty()`?

Comment: It should give error when your collection does not exist and the chain from find() breaks. But otherwise I do not have any clues.